# strtotime() doesn't warn of invalid dates

Tags: php

I am using `strtotime` to parse a date that is like `10:24 AM 22-Sep` I was then parseing this thru `checkdate`

```
 $pickup_time = strtotime($pickupTime);
 if (!checkdate(date(n,$pickup_time) ,date(j,$pickup_time), date(Y,$pickup_time)));
 {  
 echo json_encode(array("msg"=>"Nice one, that date doesn't exist. Try again.","status"=>"false")); 
 break;     
 }
```

But strtotime converts bad dates to the next logical date it would seem. So 31st Sep becomes 1 October. Completely voiding the checkdate function. Should you be able to use `strtotime()` to check for valid dates?

Comment: Think about this logically. The timstamp for the supposed '31 Sep' would be equivalent to '1 Oct' because it's merely the number of seconds since epoch. Your `checkdate()` function is completely useless, period, because if it's a timestamp, *it's always a valid date*.

Comment: One thing you could do is have them confirm what date they meant. See the demo "Type a date above" at http://www.datejs.com/ for examples of how this can look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strtotime()` doesn't have built-in validation of dates, so if you need it - perform it manually

ps: it is wrong writing `date(n,$pickup_time)`. As long as `n` **is a string** - put it within quotes: `date('n', $pickup_time)`

Answer (score 1):

*Should you be able to use strtotime() to check for valid dates?*

No, the intent of [`strtotime()`](https://www.php.net/strtotime)is to do the very best PHP can do in terms of interpreting what date you mean. From the short description on php.net:

> Parse about any English textual datetime description into a Unix
> timestamp

If your string makes no sense, `strtotime()` will still parse it. Sometimes it comes out garbage, but that's really on how you accept input from users.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the string to a date and then format it as a string that matches the format you've read in. If the strings don't match, then the date was invalid.

For example:

```
$str = '10:24 AM 22-Sep';
$d = new DateTime($str);
if ($d->format('H:i A j-M') != $str) {
    echo 'Date is invalid';
}
```

You'd need to convert the code to use the non-object version date functions. However, this only works if you're expecting a certain format.

Sorry about the edits. This is my first post.